# How to do something on a certain month?

Tags: java, android, date, webview

I have this WebView that brings up my school's lunch menu.
Is there a way to bring up a new menu every month using switch and case, or if an then?
This is the code that I have for my webview.

```
webPDF.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +
"http://www.longcountyhs.com/files/Menus/Aug_Lunch_WMS_LCHS.pdf");
```

Maybe instead of doing that, is it possible to do something like this?

```
webPDF.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +
"http://www.longcountyhs.com/files/Menus/" + "MONTH" + "_Lunch_WMS_LCHS.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the month you can use `DateFormatSymbols` along with a calendar instance.

So something like:

```
String[] monthNames = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
String myMonth = monthNames[month];
```

Comment: myMonth will then be "Jan","Feb" etc. If you make sure that you name your menus appropriately, then the menus for the current can be got if you replace "MONTH" with the myMonth value when you are loading the URL.